# question to get the correct code for a specific query from a database

Tags: mysql

i have a problem with the code to get an specific information from a database.
What i want is the number of cities repeated in each CountryCode (country).

what is get until this moment is the number of cities reapeated in each group of city.Name (groups with the same value of city.Name),

```
SELECT count(*) as numberOfCitiesRepeated,city.CountryCode from city
group by city.Name
having count(*) >1
order by countryCode
```

and thats good beacuse i only have to count the number of values group by CountryCode (country) and i will solve the problem, but i tried:

```
COUNT(SELECT count(*) as numberOfCitiesRepeated,city.CountryCode from city
group by city.Name
having count(*) >1
order by countryCode) from city group by city.CountryCode
```

and it didnt work, it doesnt compile.

thats the mysql db im using:
[image]

and this is what the first query return me:

[image]

Comment: Learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.  `city.CountryCode` must be in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ah yes, I'm thinking about this again, and I think the first query returns the cities with the same name, without taking into account that cities with the same name can belong to different countries, and i couldnt return the number of cities repeated for each country because a city with the same name can be in diferent countries. a im right?

Comment: It's the strangest thing to select one thing and group by another

Comment: Try to do `GROUP BY city.CountryCode, city.Name`

Comment: i tried <code>SELECT  city.Name, city.CountryCode FROM city
GROUP BY city.Name, city.CountryCode
HAVING count(*) > 1
order by countryCode<code> as you can see i changue the "count(*)" for "city.Name" because i wanted to verify if that name was in the database 2 or more times for the same CountryCode, and i verified it and its ok. Now what the last question i have is "if that query return me the name of the city repeated and its CountryCode how can i count the number of register which have the same CountryCode from that query?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the help of Eric and a mysql concept called VIEWS.

I could obtain the number of cities repeated of a determined country using 2 queries. In this example i get the number of cities repeated of china which its countryCode is CHN.

With this query you create a view which get the cities repeated from a country and the countrycode of the country which it belong.

```
CREATE VIEW citiesRepeatedInCountries as
SELECT  city.Name, city.CountryCode FROM city
GROUP BY city.Name, city.CountryCode
HAVING count(*) > 1
order by countryCode
```

An with this query you count the quantity of register which its countryCode is CHN.

```
select count(*) as numOfCitiesRepeatedInChina from world.citiesRepeatedInCountries 
where world.citiesRepeatedInCountries.CountryCode='CHN'
```

:)